# How to short-circuit v-model in custom directives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to have a custom directive I can attach to any `<input>` which will limit it to alpha chars only. Here's what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/m473tpfu/

It works, however, the Vue.js docs state:

> Apart from `el`, you should treat these arguments as read-only and never modify them.

So modifying `vnode` is a bad pattern. How can I achieve this differently?

Comment: I would go with an [input pattern attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp). Yours will not catch stuff pasted in, for example.

Comment: @RoyJ That won't work for my use case. `pattern` is only validated upon submit.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need to modify the vnode? I don't see any reason

Comment: I'd rather not modify the vnode. The end goal is simply to apply an input mask via a directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this: your directive has an `input` handler that checks whether forbidden chars are included, and if so, strips them out and issues a new `input` Event so that everything updates.

The usual issue of cursor moving to the end of the field when you rewrite its value applies.

```js
Vue.directive('limiter', {
  inserted(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('input', event => {
      const newValue = event.target.value;
      const cleaned = newValue.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
      
      if (newValue !== cleaned) {
        event.target.value = cleaned;
        event.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      }
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
      return {
      name: '',
    };
 }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="name" v-limiter />
  <div>
    Your name is {{ name }}.
  </div>
</div>
```